# Scroll bar is reset after the content inside is update using $selector.html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a dynamic scroll content.

First , I retrieve the data and set the content

```
    $("#sub_menu li").on("click", function () {
        $("#gallery").html(get_html($(this).attr("id")));
        $("#gallery").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    });
```

The problem is , after putting new content, if I do not specific the overflow-y, it does not have scrollbar , the content just keep its height. So , the problem is , how to update the scrollbar as well after updating content in a scrollable div?

Since I would like to use the custom scrollbar plugin, but it does not work after the content is update

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Here is the css

```
#gallery {
    width: 530px;
    float: right;
    height: 660px;
}
```

And this is the demo site, just try pressing on the "Summer 2016"

```
kotechweb.com/new_focus/page/inspiration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may it help

```
$("#sub_menu li").on("click", function () {
       $("#gallery").html(get_html($(this).attr("id"))).promise().done(function(){
            $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        });
    });
```

but I wondered why you not just use `overflow-y : auto;` and remove `$("#gallery").css("overflow-y", "scroll");`

```
#gallery {
    width: 530px;
    float: right;
    height: 660px;
    overflow-y : auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in the options of your custom scrollbar plugin `advanced:{ updateOnSelectorChange: true }` :

```
$("#gallery").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: "3d-thick",
    advanced:{ updateOnSelectorChange: true }
});
```